# Condition which may lead to a non-convexity of a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, plane-geometry, polygons, convex-geometry

Suppose $p_1p_2p_4p_6p_5p_3 p_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a convex polygon (See figure ), let $d(p_1,p_2)=x$. Here $d(.,.)$ represents an Euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given $$d(p_1,p_3) \geq x$$$$d(p_1,p_4) \geq x$$ $$d(p_2,p_3) \geq x$$ $$d(p_2,p_4) \geq x$$  $$d(p_3,p_4)< x
$$

Now, I believe that if $d(p_5,p_6) \geq x$, then at least one of $d(p_5,p_3)$, $d(p_5,p_4)$, $d(p_6,p_3)$, $d(p_6,p_4)$ is greater than $x$. Otherwise,  this polygon will lose its convexity either at $p_3$ or $p_4$.  As illustrated in figure, polygon loses its convexity at $p_3$.

PS: The order of the points should be the same as the diagram as it makes more sense to the question.
[image]

Comment: Also just for anyone reading this question, notice that it says $d(p_3,p_4)< x,
$ and not $d(p_3,p_4) \geq x.$ I missed this is first time round...

Answer (score 1):

Since $p_1p_2p_4p_6p_5p_3 p_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is convex, any ordered subsequence of $p_1p_2p_4p_6p_5p_3 p_1$ is convex also. In particular, $p_1p_2p_4 p_3 p_1$ is convex. Since $d(p_3, p_4) < d(p_1, p_2), $ the extension of the line $p_2 p_4$ meets the extension of the line $p_1 p_3$ at a point $Q$ which is closer to $p_3 p_4$ than $p_1 p_2.$ We are given that $d(p_6, p_5) \geq x.$ If $\min\{d(p_6, p_4), d(p_5, p_3)\}= d(p_6, p_4)\ $ as in the diagram below, then it is left to the reader to prove that $d(p_5, p_4) > d(p_5, p_6) = x.$ Similarly, if $\min\{d(p_6, p_4), d(p_5, p_3)\}= d(p_5, p_3)\ $ then a similar argument to the one just used to prove the previous sentence can be used to show that $d(p_6, p_3) > d(p_6, p_5) = x.$

[image]

Comment: I have left out some details which I'll maybe fill in later. But I'm busy the rest of the afternoon...